# Jquery validation validates when option is not selected and error won't clear

Tags: jquery

I'm stumped with a jquery validation problem.  At the moment, the form consists of a single checkbox, some hidden fields and a submit button.

If the checkbox is not selected, the form should submit without any fuss. If the checkbox is selected, then an additional 3 fields appear.  Of those, 1 needs to be selected and a text box filled before the form will submit.

However, should I uncheck the checkbox, the form will still insist that I still have to make a selection - even though unchecking hides all the options, clears all values and errors. It should submit but won't for some reason and won't clear out the error message once the message is displayed- and that's where I need help.

I think I need to do an additional check to require 1 option from the group selected when that checkbox is selected, but so far I've not been able to get it to work.

Code is below and I also have a working CodePen test at https://codepen.io/43rdworld/pen/dyMQgJG

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title><?=$pageTitle;?></title>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="theForm" id="theForm" action="#">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label for="updateNum">Change Number: </label>
                    <input name="updateNum" type="checkbox" id="updateNum" value="1" tabindex="1">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="showWrapper" style="display:none;">
                    <div>
                        <label for="newRadio"><input name="number" id="newRadio" type="radio" class="newNumGroup" value="1"> Enter New Number</label>
                        <div id="newWrapper" style="display:none;margin-left:25px !important;">
                            <label>New Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="newText" id="newText"></label>
                            <div id="newError" class="error errorContainer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="chgRadio"><input name="number" type="radio" id="chgRadio" class="newNumGroup" value="2"> Change Existing Number</label>
                        <div id="chgWrapper" style="display:none;margin-left:25px !important;">
                            <label>Change Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="chgText" id="chgText"></label>
                            <div id="chgError" class="errorContainer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <label for="movRadio"><input name="number" type="radio" id="movRadio" class="newNumGroup" value="3"> Move Existing Number</label>
                        <div id="movWrapper" style="display:none;margin-left:25px !important;">
                            <label>Move Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="movText" id="movText"></label>
                            <div id="movError" class="errorContainer"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="updateError" class="errorContainer"></div>
            </div>
            <div><br><br><input name="submitForm" type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit" tabindex="-99"></div>
        </form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js" integrity="sha512-6Uv+497AWTmj/6V14BsQioPrm3kgwmK9HYIyWP+vClykX52b0zrDGP7lajZoIY1nNlX4oQuh7zsGjmF7D0VZYA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#theForm").validate({
                    ignore: [],
                    groups: {
                        newNumGroup: "newNum,changeNum,moveNum','newNumGroup"
                    },
                    rules: {
                        updateNum: {
                            requiredIfChecked: true,
                            require_from_group: [1, ".newNumGroup"]
                        },
                        newText: {
                            required:  {
                                depends: function(el) {
                                    return $("#newRadio").is(':checked');
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        chgText: {
                            required:  {
                                depends: function(el) {
                                    return $("#chgRadio").is(':checked');
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        movText: {
                            required:  {
                                depends: function(el) {
                                    return $("#movRadio").is(':checked');
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        if(element.attr("name")==="updateNum") {
                            $("#updateError").html(error);
                        } else if (element.attr("name") === "newText") {
                            $("#newError").html(error);
                        } else if (element.attr("name") === "chgText") {
                            $("#chgError").html(error);
                        } else if (element.attr("name") === "movText") {
                            $("#movError").html(error);
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        updateNum: {
                            require_from_group: '* Select One of the Options Below'
                        },
                        newText: {
                            required: '* Number Required 1'
                        },
                        chgText: {
                            required: '* Number Required 2'
                        },
                        movText: {
                            required: '* Number Required 3'
                        },
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        if (confirm('This is a test message'))
                        {
                            // alert('valid form');
                            // return false;
                            form.submit();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('not valid form');
                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#updateNum").on('click', function() {
                    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $("#showWrapper").fadeIn();
                        $("#updateError").empty();
                    } else {
                        $("#updateError").empty();
                        $("#showWrapper").fadeOut();
                        $("newWrapper").fadeOut();
                        $("#newRadio").prop('checked', false);
                        $("#newText").val('');

                        $("#chgWrapper").fadeOut();
                        $("#chgRadio").prop('checked', false);
                        $("#chgText").val('');

                        $("#movWrapper").fadeOut();
                        $("#movRadio").prop('checked', false);
                        $("#movText").val('');
                    }
                });
                $("#newRadio").on('click', function() {
                    $("#newWrapper").fadeIn();
                    $("#chgWrapper,#movWrapper").fadeOut();
                    $("#chgRadio,#movRadio").prop('checked', false);
                    $("#chgText,#movText").val('');
                    $("#chgError,#movError").empty();
                });
                $("#chgRadio").on('click', function() {
                    $("#chgWrapper").fadeIn();
                    $("#newWrapper,#movWrapper").fadeOut();
                    $("#newRadio,#movRadio").prop('checked', false);
                    $("#newText,#movText").val('');
                    $("#newError,#movError").empty();
                });
                $("#movRadio").on('click', function() {
                    $("#movWrapper").fadeIn();
                    $("#newWrapper,#chgWrapper").fadeOut();
                    $("#newRadio,#chgRadio").prop('checked', false);
                    $("#newText,#chgText").val('');
                    $("#newError,#chgError").empty();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if is not checked, remove required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified to do the `validation` process based on what you want to achieve. I have **refactored** and **simplified** your complete `code` and is working as expected now.

Firstly, instead of checking `radio` buttons as in group you can assign input names as array type `myRadio[]` which then we will use for `validation` in `jQuery`

In your `rules` for this you can `depends` on the checkbox to be checked for this `validation` to occur or `else` submit the `form` without any fuss.

```
'myRadio[]': {
  required: {
    depends: function(el) {
      return $("#updateNum").is(':checked');
    }
  }
},
```

The `input` type text validation will stay the same since they are all independent to the each radio button being `checked` or `not` - the error placement stays the same as well.

The rest of `jQuery` is all simplified to few `lines` only instead of repeating the `code` again and again. You can assign a `class` your `input` text and use `$.each` function to remove all `values` if the `checkbox` is unchecked - same goes for setting the `prop` to false as well.

To show `each` input text below each `radio` button you can simply use `one` function which will `work` on all those **three** radio buttons by using a class `newNumGroup` and a `change` event function on it. Check `if` the radio is `checked` and also `attr` of it it matches then `show` the relevant `div` using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) with a `class` and [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) index method to `fadeIn`

**Complete live working Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Validation
  $("#theForm").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
      'myRadio[]': {
        required: {
          depends: function(el) {
            return $("#updateNum").is(':checked');
          }
        }
      },
      newText: {
        required: {
          depends: function(el) {
            return $("#newRadio").is(':checked');
          }
        }
      },
      chgText: {
        required: {
          depends: function(el) {
            return $("#chgRadio").is(':checked');
          }
        }
      },
      movText: {
        required: {
          depends: function(el) {
            return $("#movRadio").is(':checked');
          }
        }
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr("name") === "newText") {
        $("#newError").html(error);
      } else if (element.attr("name") === "chgText") {
        $("#chgError").html(error);
      } else if (element.attr("name") === "movText") {
        $("#movError").html(error);
      } else {
        $("#updateError").html(error);
      }
    },
    messages: {
      'myRadio[]': {
        required: '* Select One of the Options above'
      },
      newText: {
        required: '* Number Required 1'
      },
      chgText: {
        required: '* Number Required 2'
      },
      movText: {
        required: '* Number Required 3'
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      if (confirm('Form ready to submit')) {
        form.submit();
      } else {
        alert('not valid form');
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  //checkbox change event
  $("#updateNum").on('change', function() {
    $("#error").empty();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#showWrapper").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $("#showWrapper").fadeOut(); //fadeOut Parent
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').fadeOut(); //fadeout childrens
      //Prop checked false
      $('input[name="myRadio[]"]').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).prop('checked', false);
      })
      //remove all values
      $('.newMobileTextinput').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).val('')
      })
    }
  });

  //Radio button change event
  $(".newNumGroup").on('change', function() {
    $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').fadeOut(); //fadeout all
    //New
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'newRadio') {
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').eq(0).find('input').val('') //empty input
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').eq(0).fadeIn();
    }
    //Change
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'chgRadio') {
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').eq(1).fadeIn();
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').eq(1).find('input').val('') //empty input
    }
    //Move
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'movRadio') {
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').eq(2).fadeIn();
      $("#showWrapper").find('.newMobileWrapper').eq(2).find('input').val('') //empty input
    }
    //Empty errors
    $('.newMobileError').empty();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Something</title>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js" integrity="sha512-6Uv+497AWTmj/6V14BsQioPrm3kgwmK9HYIyWP+vClykX52b0zrDGP7lajZoIY1nNlX4oQuh7zsGjmF7D0VZYA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form name="theForm" id="theForm" action="#">
    <div>
      <div>
        <label for="updateNum">Change Number: </label>
        <input name="updateNum" type="checkbox" id="updateNum" value="1" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="showWrapper" style="display:none;">
        <div>
          <label for="newRadio"><input name="myRadio[]" id="newRadio" type="radio" class="newNumGroup" value="1"> Enter New Number</label>
          <div id="newWrapper" class="newMobileWrapper" style="display:none;margin-left:25px !important;">
            <label>New Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="newText"  class="newMobileTextinput" id="newText"></label>
            <div id="newError" class="newMobileError errorContainer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
          <label for="chgRadio"><input name="myRadio[]" type="radio" id="chgRadio" class="newNumGroup" value="2"> Change Existing Number</label>
          <div id="chgWrapper" class="newMobileWrapper" style="display:none;margin-left:25px !important;">
            <label>Change Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="chgText"  class="newMobileTextinput" id="chgText"></label>
            <div id="chgError" class="newMobileError errorContainer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
          <label for="movRadio"><input name="myRadio[]" type="radio" id="movRadio" class="newNumGroup" value="3"> Move Existing Number</label>
          <div id="movWrapper" class="newMobileWrapper" style="display:none;margin-left:25px !important;">
            <label>Move Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="movText" class="newMobileTextinput" id="movText"></label>
            <div id="movError" class="newMobileError errorContainer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="updateError" class="errorContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div><br><br><input name="submitForm" type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit" tabindex="-99"></div>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cool - thanks so much.  I knew it would be something simple but just couldn't see it.  Thanks so much.